# Github Actions: Auto commenting a console output on a pull request

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

I am trying to set up a github actions that automatically comment the size delta after a build on a pull request. Essentially I need the output of the "calculate code size delta" command to be included in a comment that is automatically created on pull requests.

Here is what the 2 steps of the action looks like right now:

```
- name: Diff revision
    id: diff_rev
    shell: bash
    working-directory: cobrax
    run: |
      echo "::set-output name=delta_code::$(python3 codesizes.py diff build/zephyr/zephyr.elf)\n"
      
  - name: Auto Comment
    uses: bubkoo/auto-comment@v1
    with:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      pullRequestOpened: >
         @{{ author }}
        Thank you for raising your pull request.
        This is the code delta:
        ${{join(steps.diff_rev.outputs.delta_code, '\n')}}
        Please make sure you have followed our contributing guidelines. We will review it as soon as possible
```

The console displays the following result:

```
Using git merge-base against master branch    
Comparing code size of current .elf against: 30ac63fd5ea039c7b874a999f928f41220ad883f
    +---------+--------+-------+-------+
    |  Region |  .text | .data |  .bss |
    +---------+--------+-------+-------+
    |   Local | 113298 |  2412 | 31355 |
    | Against | 113298 |  2412 | 31355 |
    |   Delta |      0 |     0 |     0 |
    +---------+--------+-------+-------+\n
```

As you can clearly see, I used set-output to store the result (Or, I think that's what it does) and then use the output variable on the comment. But that obviously does not work.

The output of the bubkoo/auto-comment action is:

```
octokit.reactions.deleteLegacy() is deprecated, see https://developer.github.com/v3/reactions/#delete-a-reaction-legacy
(node:3588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: HttpError: Not Found
    at /__w/_actions/bubkoo/auto-comment/v1/dist/index.js.cache.js:1:76457
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:3588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3588) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

And, the comment displays as: "[...] This is the code delta: Using git merge-base against master branch Please make sure [...]". The phrase "Using git merge-base agains master branch does get appended to the comment but not the whole console output apparently.

What am I doing wrong and how would you go about doing this using github actions ?

Thank you for your help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the output contains multiple lines and only the first line is assigned to the variable. As seen on a [post](https://github.community/t/set-output-truncates-multiline-strings/16852) on the GitHub Support Community, you can escape the newline characters to have a single line which gets expanded automatically when used. Another thing to consider is that you should leave one line of space in the `.yml` in order to start a new line in the GitHub comment later on.

*Your snippet should work like this:*

````
- name: Diff revision
  id: diff_rev
  shell: bash
  working-directory: cobrax
  run: |
    delta=$(python3 codesizes.py diff build/zephyr/zephyr.elf)
    delta="${delta//'%'/'%25'}"
    delta="${delta//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
    delta="${delta//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
    echo "::set-output name=delta_code::$delta"

- name: Auto Comment
  uses: bubkoo/auto-comment@v1
  with:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    pullRequestOpened: >
       @{{ author }}
      
      Thank you for raising your pull request.
      
      This is the code delta:
      
      ```
      
      ${{ steps.diff_rev.outputs.delta_code }}
      
      ```
      
      Please make sure you have followed our contributing guidelines. We will review it as soon as possible.
````

---

A sample with `$(git log)`:

[image: screenshot]

Full `auto-comment.yml`:

````
name: Auto Comment

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Diff revision
        id: diff_rev
        shell: bash
        run: |
          delta=$(git log)
          delta="${delta//'%'/'%25'}"
          delta="${delta//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
          delta="${delta//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
          echo "::set-output name=delta_code::$delta"

      - name: Auto Comment
        uses: bubkoo/auto-comment@v1
        with:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          pullRequestOpened: >
             @{{ author }}
            
            Thank you for raising your pull request.
            
            This is the code delta:
            
            ```
            
            ${{ steps.diff_rev.outputs.delta_code }}
            
            ```
            
            Please make sure you have followed our contributing guidelines. We will review it as soon as possible.
````